# WordPress : Password Protected Page Format

Tags: wordpress, password-protection, visual-editor

I have tried editing the format of password protected page and it was successful. But my client asked if it's possible to change the format of the password protected page using the Visual Editor in WordPress admin.

I am hoping for your immediate reply, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short and simple answer is no. I've been using wordpress for a long time and there is no readily available plugin or method to do this that doesn't involve a lot of custom coding.

The closest that I know of is the plugin [WP-Admin Theme plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-admin-theme/). But it seems to be quite old. There are probably others but I believe they are geared more to CSS overrides than using the in-built wysiwyg editor of worpdress. This means that your client would need to know some basic html and css in order to use it.

For more information on creating admin themes there is some Wordpress meta: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes

I don't like to plug for pay products but I also did find this:  [Tailored login from I-Themes](https://ithemes.com/purchase/tailored-login/).  However if there is a commercial product i'm sure if you search the WP plugins database hard enough you might find a free product that is similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll just report to my client that it's not possible. Thank you very much!

Comment: I edited my answer - I did locate a commercial product that I think does what you are looking for.  Keep checking through the WP plugin DB, there may be something in there that I've been unaware of.

Comment: Thanks! But I guess my client prefers to use the Visual Editor so I'll just have to report that it's not possible. Thank you!

Comment: Visual editor (wysiwyg editor) of wordpress is for page content, posts and comments. What you would need is a visual theme editor, and specifically an admin page theme editor, because the login page is a bit abstracted from the templates of the primary wordpress page set, it uses entirely different php, css and template than the core.

Comment: thanks! Is it safe to suggest to just use the Editor in WordPress? Appearance > Editor.

Comment: Looking at the appearance editor for some of the themes I use, I don't see the login page on there, but I don't use any themes with a themed login page - i'm just going to have to assume admin themes will be able to do this.

Comment: Actually, this isn't about the login page. It's a password-protected page and from the WordPress admin editor, the client can edit functions.php, is it safe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62999/discussion-between-tremor-and-monica-negapatan).